# Question related to future tense

Tags: future-tense, future-time

Seems that the same thought about future can be expressed in two ways. For instance:

> **Are** you **working** tomorrow?
>
> **Will** you **work** tomorrow?

So the question is, are there any difference between them?

Comment: You'd be more likely to use the first format if you were thinking in terms of how working/not working tomorrow might affect the *current* situation (i.e. - *Are you working tomorrow? If not, let's go out and get really drunk tonight, and we can sleep it off in the morning*). You might use the second if you're inviting the other person to *make a decision now* about whether to work or not. If he doesn't have the power to make that decision (it's already fixed by his employment contract, say) you might be more likely to ask *Will you be working tomorrow?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in most languages, in English there's more than one way to say many things.  The present progressive tense, when combined with something that indicates future action, is *roughly* the same as the simple future tense.

"I am working tomorrow" = "I will work tomorrow"

"She's flying to Hawaii this evening" = "She will fly to Hawaii this evening"

"Aren't you going to see your aunt this weekend" = "Won't you see your aunt this weekend?"

And so on.  *However*, this is not a solid rule and there are some uses where the two are different.  For example:

"What are we having for dinner?"  is a question that implies that *you* are making dinner, whereas,  "What will we have for dinner?" is a question that implies either of us could make dinner (or we could go out to eat).

"Will" can also imply a more definite situation.  "I *will* close this deal tomorrow" is stronger than "I'm *going* to close this deal tomorrow."